# Wordpress plugin form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, form-submit, wordpress-plugin-creation

In my WordPress plugin code, I have 2 forms. The second form appears when I submit the first form. However, the problem is that the submit button of the second form is not displaying an echo.

```
     
// Code du premier formulaire :
function hotel_booking_form()
{
    $arrival_date = isset($_POST['arrival-date']) ? $_POST['arrival-date'] : '';
    $departure_date = isset($_POST['departure-date']) ? $_POST['departure-date'] : '';
    $adults = isset($_POST['adults0']) ? $_POST['adults0'] : '0';
    $children = isset($_POST['children0']) ? $_POST['children0'] : '0';
    $children_ages = isset($_POST['child-age-0']) ? $_POST['child-age-0'] : array();

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <form id="hotel-booking-form" method="post" action="">
        <label for="datetimes">Arrival and Departure Dates:</label>
        <input type="text" name="datetimes" id="datetimes" value="<?php echo ($arrival_date && $departure_date) ? ($arrival_date . ' - ' . $departure_date) : ''; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="arrival-date" id="arrival-date" value="<?php echo $arrival_date; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="departure-date" id="departure-date" value="<?php echo $departure_date; ?>" />

        <?php
        render_chambre_form(0, $adults, $children, $children_ages);

        $chambreIndex = 1;
        while (isset($_POST['adults' . $chambreIndex])) {
            $adults = $_POST['adults' . $chambreIndex];
            $children = $_POST['children' . $chambreIndex];
            $children_ages = isset($_POST['child-age-' . $chambreIndex]) ? $_POST['child-age-' . $chambreIndex] : array();
            render_chambre_form($chambreIndex, $adults, $children, $children_ages);
            $chambreIndex++;
        }
        ?>

        <div id="additional-chambres-container">
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="add-chambre-btn" value="Add room">
        <input id="btn-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/js/hotel-booking.js', __FILE__); ?>"></script>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        hotel_booking_process_form();
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
// Code du deuxième formulaire :
function hotel_booking_process_form()
{
    // ...
    ?>
    <div id="additional-form-container">
        <form id="additional-form" method="post" action="">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required><br>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required><br>
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required><br>
            <button type="submit" name="confirm">Confirm</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
        echo '*****************';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second form would need to be submitted first, before `$_POST['confirm']` could be set. Question is - are you doing anything to call `hotel_booking_process_form` _again_, after that second form was submitted?

Comment: No, I only call it within the context of the first form.

Comment: That first form does not have any element named `confirm`, so you can not expect `$_POST['confirm']` to be set when you are processing the data submitted by that first form.

Comment: So, how can i solve this issue? How can i handle the submission of the second form and set $_POST['confirm']?

Comment: It already _gets_ set, when you submit that second form. You just need to place your condition, based on which you will process the submitted data, somewhere else - and _not_ in a part of the code, that will not even execute any more, after that second form was submitted.